# Why there is combination of earlyclobber and matching constraint in C inline assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, inline-assembly

The code I met is in linux kernel in `arch/x86/lib/usercopy_32.c`:

```
#define __copy_user(to, from, size)                 \
do {                                    \
    int __d0, __d1, __d2;                       \
    __asm__ __volatile__(                       \
        "   cmp  $7,%0\n"                   \
        "   jbe  1f\n"                  \
        "   movl %1,%0\n"                   \
        "   negl %0\n"                  \
        "   andl $7,%0\n"                   \
        "   subl %0,%3\n"                   \
        "4: rep; movsb\n"                   \
        "   movl %3,%0\n"                   \
        "   shrl $2,%0\n"                   \
        "   andl $3,%3\n"                   \
        "   .align 2,0x90\n"                \
        "0: rep; movsl\n"                   \
        "   movl %3,%0\n"                   \
        "1: rep; movsb\n"                   \
        "2:\n"                          \
        ".section .fixup,\"ax\"\n"              \
        "5: addl %3,%0\n"                   \
        "   jmp 2b\n"                   \
        "3: lea 0(%3,%0,4),%0\n"                \
        "   jmp 2b\n"                   \
        ".previous\n"                       \
        _ASM_EXTABLE(4b,5b)                 \
        _ASM_EXTABLE(0b,3b)                 \
        _ASM_EXTABLE(1b,2b)                 \
        : "=&c"(size), "=&D" (__d0), "=&S" (__d1), "=r"(__d2)   \
        : "3"(size), "0"(size), "1"(to), "2"(from)      \
        : "memory");                        \
} while (0)
```

This is a bit complex but basically it just copy `size` bytes from address `from` to address `to`.  The detail of the above code may not be really important (I show the code just to say that there is a real usage which combines earlyclobber and matching constraint) .

My question is:

Why we need earlyclobber while we have matching constraint? Since earlyclobber is aimed at preventing to use the same register for input and output, but matching constraint means they should use the same register? Is not this contradictory ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, early-clobber isn't necessary here because there aren't any operands where the compiler has a choice of what register to pick (or even any which aren't matching constraints and thus equivalent to `"+r"` read+write outputs).

It's not contradictory.  Early-clobber means the output is written before the last read of *any* input.  If you had a statement like this:

```
asm("..." : "=&r"(dst) : "0"(x), "r"(y) : "memory");
```

The early clobber would be necessary if the template writes `dst` before reading `y`.  It would stop the `"r"` constraint from picking the same register as `%0`, which it might in a case where the compiler knew `x == y`.

Using a matching constraint to force `x` to pick the same register as the `dst` output is fine; the compiler will do what you tell it.  This would make sense if the template is something like `"inc %0; imul %2, %0"` which reads+writes `%0`, and then reads `y` (and the new value of `%0`).

It doesn't need to read `x` after `dst` is written, only `y`, so it's fine to force `x` into the same register as `dst`.

Comment: I think I basically understand what you mean. But there are one question about your answer.

You said "This would make sense if the template is something like "inc %0; imul %2, %0" which reads+writes %0, and then reads y (and the new value of %0)."



What the last part in parentheses means ? Do you means if the template asm read `y` will get the new value of `%0` or just means that we can read y and %0 arbitrarily and still get the original value of `y` instead of new `%0`

Comment: @huangjl: I mean `inc %0` changes `%0`, and that `imul %2, %0` reads both its operands  and writes `%0`.  Would it be clearer if I'd used `"+&a"(x)` and said "the new value of EAX"?  At that point it's no longer the original C variable `x`.  But yes, `%2` still has the value of the C variable `y` since we've only written an early-clobber output, so it's still safe to read other inputs.